# Re-rendering Angular after adding folders

Tags: angular

I ran *ng new* on the shopping cart code I had but it skipped copying over a couple of folders. Then I added the folders manually by copying and pasting but the code didn't work. Can I update angular code manually in this way?

Comment: `ng new` is used to create a brand new Angular project. Not for "updating code". So no, you can't update code this way. https://angular.io/cli/new

Answer (score 0):

Which folders did you copy.  And ng new is for new project creation in angular which should create a new folder and then it creates the project related files in it so the skipped files is the point for it.

Did you run ng serve for running the project and then added the folders and files in to the project then the files would not work in that scenario.  You have stop the serve and then again do `ng serve` command because for running the project a build is created

Comment: It didn't create the components folder from this project here: http://learningprogramming.net/mean-stack/angular-6/build-shopping-cart-in-angular-6/

Comment: It changed a bunch of the files as well and they didn't work until I copied and pasted into the files from the project's URL. It's working now.